# Serializing RowMutation

Tags: java, cassandra

Inside the Cassandra source trunk on Github (https://github.com/apache/cassandra), there's an example of writing data in `examples/client_only/src/ClientOnlyExample.java`:

```
private static void testWriting() throws Exception
    {
        // do some writing.
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            RowMutation change = new RowMutation(KEYSPACE, ByteBufferUtil.bytes(("key" + i)));
            ColumnPath cp = new ColumnPath(COLUMN_FAMILY).setColumn(("colb").getBytes());
            change.add(new QueryPath(cp), ByteBufferUtil.bytes(("value" + i)), 0);

            // don't call change.apply().  The reason is that is makes a static call into Table, which will perform
            // local storage initialization, which creates local directories.
            // change.apply();

            StorageProxy.mutate(Arrays.asList(change), ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
            System.out.println("wrote key" + i);
        }
        System.out.println("Done writing.");
    }
```

I'm looking to serialize the data into a readable format (JSON) where the writes seem to happen, `org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy`, inside of the method `performWrite`:

```
public static IWriteResponseHandler performWrite(IMutation mutation,
            ConsistencyLevel consistency_level,
            String localDataCenter,
            WritePerformer performer)
            throws UnavailableException, IOException
    {
...
```

The `IMutation` parameter appears to be what I want, as `RowMutation` implements that class. I can get the table (keyspace), and the column families out, but can't seem to get the column name/values. If I'm inside of the mentioned method, how do I get that information from `IMutation mutation`?

```
// keyspace
String table = mutation.getTable();

// TODO won't work with batch?
UUID cfId = mutation.getColumnFamilyIds().iterator().next();

// column family name cfMetadata.cfName
CFMetaData cfMetadata = Schema.instance.getCFMetaData(cfId);

// row key 
RowMutation data = new RowMutation(table, mutation.key());
String row = ByteBufferUtil.bytesToHex(data.key());

// column name/values ??
// data. ....
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked in the [row mutation source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cassandra/cassandra-all/0.8.0-beta1/org/apache/cassandra/db/RowMutation.java) where there was on same package a RowMutationSerializer which has method

```
       serialize(RowMutation, DataOutputStream, int)
```

Could this serve for something?

Comment: Actually, you got me thinking now. It looks like that has potential. Will try out tomorrow!

Comment: Couldn't seem to get that to work inside StorageProxy. Wondering if `RowMutation.apply` might be a better spot for this.